# Angular resource REST has no method '$save'

Tags: angularjs

I would like to interact with a REST API using `$resource` but when calling the save method I get `has no method '$save'` error. My code is inspired by the answer found on [AngularJS $resource RESTful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269882/angularjs-resource-restful-example)

```
myapp.factory('Monitoring', function($resource) {
   return $resource('http://localhost:8080/wepapp/network/v1/cronjobs/:id', { id: '@id' } );
});
```

Q1: What is the purpose of `@` in `{ id: '@id' }`? I found it in most of the examples.

```
myapp.factory('MonitoringCRUDControllerService', ['Monitoring', function(Monitoring) {
    return {
        create: function(id, command, schedule) {
            console.log("create");
            console.log(command);
            console.log(schedule);
            Monitoring.id = id;
            Monitoring.command = command;
            Monitoring.schedule = schedule;
            console.log(Monitoring);
            Monitoring.$save();
        }
    }
}]);
```

The `Monitoring` object is correctly injected:

```
function Resource(value){
        copy(value || {}, this);
      }
```

Calling the `$save` failed with the error `has no method '$save'`.

Q2: What the purpose of `$` before save?

Q3: What am I missing to make the save method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your `Monitoring` class like this (not tested):

```
var m = new Monitoring({id:id});
m.command = command;
m.schedule = schedule;
m.$save();
```

The documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) has a similar example:

```
var newCard = new CreditCard({number:'0123'});
newCard.name = "Mike Smith";
newCard.$save();
```

I asked the same question about the `@` sign a while ago: ["at" sign in parameter names in resource definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313971/at-sign-in-parameter-names-in-resource-definition). Basically `@` sign means that the value will be read from the object's property. Or as the same documentation says:

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that
>   parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET
>   operations).

The `$` is not any special character, it is just a part of the method name.

Comment: The error is gone but I noticed that in Chrome, the called URL does not contains the port number and the method type is OPTIONS: `OPTIONS http://localhost/wepapp/network/v1/cronjobs`. Any reason for that behaviour? Does `$resource` handles JSONP?

Comment: I do not think that JSONP would work. I think angular expects JSON data from the URL. I am not sure why it omits the port number. The documentation says that port numbers are respected. Try running it on the default port and see if it works.

Comment: For the port I needed to escape `:` with '\\:'

Comment: do you use the latest angular?

Comment: the reason why it did `OPTIONS` before you escaped the colon was because without the port number this is a different domain, so the browser was sending a so called CORS "preflight" request.